# Multiple data frame columns plotted in the same bar without overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Date':['03-19-2019'],
    'Total':[35],
    'Solved':[19],
    'Arrived':[23],
    } 

 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

and I want to plot a bar plot like this:

[image]

with

```
df1.plot(kind='barh',x='Date',y='Total', ax=ax0, color='#C0C0C0', 
width=0.5)
df1.plot(kind='barh',x='Date',y='Arrived', ax=ax0, color='#C0FFFF', 
width=0.5)
df1.plot(kind='barh',x='Date',y='Solved', ax=ax0, color='#C0C0FF', 
width=0.5)
```

However, to avoid overlapping, I have to draw each column taking into account which of them has the bigger value.(Total greater than Arrived greater than Solved)

How can I avoid to do this and automate this process easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a straightforward and simpler approach in Pandas but I just came up with this quick workaround. The idea is following:

- Leave out the first column `Date` and sort the remaining columns.
- Use the sorted indices for plotting the columns in ascending order
- To make the colors consistent, you can make use of dictionary so that the ascending/descending order doesn't affect your colors.

---

```
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()

ids = np.argsort(df1.values[0][1:])[::-1]
colors = {'Total': '#C0C0C0', 'Arrived': '#C0FFFF', 'Solved':'#C0C0FF'}

for col in np.array(df1.columns[1:].tolist())[ids]:
    df1.plot(kind='barh',x='Date',y=col, ax=ax0, color=colors[col], width=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! the only disadvantage I can see with this approach is that the colors dont represent always the same type of data

Comment: @Laura: I edited my solution to make the colors represent always the same items using a dictionary

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

A stacked bar graph can be produced in pandas via the `stacked=True` option. To use this you need to make the `"Date"` the index first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Date':['03-19-2019'],
    'Total':[35],
    'Solved':[19],
    'Arrived':[23],
    } 

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df.set_index("Date").plot(kind="barh", stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Comparing your figure with OP's figure in the question, it seems he/she doesn't want a stacked bar chart but all the bars to start at x=0 but zorder arranged such that the lowest bar is at the front and the highest at the back. Compare the numbers on the x-axis

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , Bazingaa is right. I wanted all bars start as 0. I have solved now taking into account the solution provided by him/her. Thanks